# Get Stream and save as jpeg (image) file from IP Camera using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, rtp, mpeg-4

How i can get stream from Ip Camera, Its using RTP, stream is MPEG4, i have multicast address and port,and i have ip camera's IP address and Port Number. 
And I cant reach via http forexample (http://ip/jpeg) And I cant reach stream with VLC Player too. forexample (rtp://ipadressofcam:port) and (**rtp://multicastaddress:port**) 
So What is ffmpeg command of that?
I have windows OS, I only write code with C# right now.
But producer created their own ocx which used for viewing cam,that plugin can work on .net but i dont want to use it becouse it doesnt have much funcionality, I mean you cant get current picture or snapshot of cams, thats why i have to do it myself.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cameraviewer.aspx

Comment: you can dowload the code and have a look at it.

Comment: i did it all used take stream from http, but i cant get becouse it doesnt support! to process stream is not easy thing i know! as i said even VLC cant take stream via RTP!

Comment: I read all of your comments.  But I still don't believe vlc can't open it. BTW its syntax is rtp://@multicastaddress:port not rtp://multicastaddress:port

Comment: @L.B thanks, but yes it doesnt. btw are you sure about @ ? can you show me reference?

Comment: `are you sure about @ ? can you show me reference` Have you tried it? I am not interested in proving it. Do your own search.

Comment: @L.B I m asking becouse according to your logic i have to try all character in my keybord! # ? $? @? %?....

Comment: Again you are commenting without any googling. http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html . More specifically scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: @L.B well thanks, i will try it at work, but i dont get it! so i dont write multicastaddress right?

Comment: Here is another source http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/911984 . Just search for `rtp://@`. So you don't have to try all characters in your keyboard.

Comment: @L.B ohh ok :) thanks for your help i will try them at work! i will inform it will take or not

Comment: What is the camera's make + model? Some IP camera have the option of streaming in m-jpeg or dumping jpg files at regular intervals.

Comment: @L.B i just try as rtp://@ and its not getting stream with VLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the stream is not password-protected?

Try to see why your camera rejects VLC requests. And this is how to do it: Install Wireshark, start it, and put a filter for the camera address, like: ip.addr == camera_ip (xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx). Then, try to connect with VLC, and look there at the messages exchanged. If you see a DROP, UNAUTH, or something that tells you to use a passwd, introduce it. (VLC will first try to connect using an unauthenticated procedure, and if it fails, will ask for a passwd.)

Wireshark will give you clues if the failure reason is something different.

And keep in mind that if VLC can't access it, the chance to find some other way to do it is almost zero. Unless you're a video guru.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answer, i dont care if vlc open it, i just neet to control that stream with c# thats it. but thanks for info again

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLC for such a thing ,and it's ActiveX control which is available for .NET also ,just need to install VLC Media Player and you can set it's control on VS toolbox

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=54969

**UPDATE**

If you are ready to pay for this stuff you can use http://www.mainconcept.com/products/sdks/video.html this Company product's to advance with Decoding and Encoding ,where you can find a huge Library .

Comment: well i dont know than it must be an Compression Issue ,Container or Codec because im pretty sure VLC Can ,and i tested it ..A LOT !!

Comment: @mekici why do you think VLC cannot open it ,Protocol issue ,Container Issue or Codec Issue if you can send us a sample i can provide you some tools which you can use !

Comment: @mekici if you can record a portion of that Video i can analyze it for you !

Comment: how can i do that? you mean recording view as .avi or?

Comment: @mekici can we continue this at chat ?

Comment: @mekici Decoding Stream with c#

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4867/discussion-between-cody-and-mekici)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to receive video stream from camera and convert individual frame into JPEG file. This sounds good and actually sounds natural: why not? there is a video feed being sent on network and we don't need much, just to pick individual frame.

The original stream is MPEG-4 (Part 2) and desired target encoding is JPEG. This breaks the task into parts of getting MPEG-4 video feed, decoding it into uncompressed images, and encoding into JPEG. Let us go through these from the last one backwards.

JPEG is a popular encoding and there are various codecs with different interface capable of compressing into JPEG. Options include [GDI+ API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [IJG JPEG library libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/), JPEG libraries and codecs for video with DirectShow and other interfaces.

MPEG-4 decoder is a complicated component, however is luckily well standardized and available in different interfaces and from several sources. In particular [MPEG-4 Part 2 Video Decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  is shipped as `DMO` (and also through ) with Windows 7. Decoder is also available as DirectShow filter in ffdshow, Intel Media SDK.

Back to the first step, you need to reach MPEG-4 stream from network. First of all you indicated that the camera is available on multi-cast UDP address. This makes you open a socket and put into onto multi-cast group in order to start receiving RTP data. The data you would receive is not pure MPEG-4 yet, and is formatted according to [RTP Payload Format for MPEG-4 Audio/Visual Streams](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3016.txt) and as you receive RTP stream of messages you will have to be prepared to receive out of order fragments, packet losses etc. You are supposed to receive what you can receive, check the RTP headers, and do your best in reconstructing MPEG-4 feed.

Eventually you need to cover these steps (not necessarily directly, you would rather use third party libraries including those mentioned in other answers) from your application and build a pipeline which stitches together receiving from network and transcoding.

Answer (score 0):

So until now, I saw VLC cant open it but if we create .sdp file and play it with ffplay only a black screen appears.

```
vlc -vvv dshow:// --sout-keep --sout-all --sout=#rtp{dst=multicastaddress,port=portNo,sdp=file:///C:/test/my.sdp}
```

Of course this is not pure solution but there is little bit hope.

But obsolute solution can be like that;
There is no way to use just c# to achive what i intend. There are few c++ library components that i can use, but i can use it along with Managed c++ to write interop services and use those dlls in my c# code.Here is what i need:

1-I need an RTP Library, http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib or live555 but live555 has certain limitations.
2-RTP Library is the transport for the MPEG4 stream i pull from my encoder. But i need ways to control the stream, those are provided producer's WSDLs.
3-After that i need a decoder; Libavcodec, I can use libavcodec to convert an Iframe to a jpeg image in .net.