# Write RTP Stream Data to file

Tags: c++, streaming, udp, rtp

I have written an application which triggers an IP Camera to stream it's data (`MPEG4`) over `RTP`. This works fine so far - I start to setup and start the stream with the corresponding `RTSP` commands ( `DESCRIBE`, `SETUP` and `PLAY` ).

While streaming I receive the usual `Sender Reports` and send my own `Receiver Reports` - Everything is working fine here.

Now with the application mentioned above, I do **NOT** read the stream. I have a seperate hardware , which just logs all the stuff going over the Ethernet ( a little bit like Wireshark ). Now when the whole streaming is finished I can download those logs from my hardware and extract data from them.

So what I have then is a logfile with all the data from the `RTP` stream as raw data.

My question would now is: How do I write this appropriately into a MPEG4 file? I know this is a very broad question and I don't expect to get a step-by-step tutorial. But actually I am a bit overwhelmed and don't know where to start.If I just memcpy all the Payload from the RTP messages sequentially into a MPEG4 file it doesn't work. Now I am also a bit confused by SDP and stuff.
Well maybe someone has a link or some help for me..?

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740265/get-stream-and-save-as-jpeg-image-file-from-ip-camera-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed from MPEG4 to H.264 - it actually was a little bit easier to write a video file like this. For H.264 this answer covers it pretty much:

[How to process raw UDP packets so that they can be decoded by a decoder filter in a directshow source filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)

Answer (score 1):

You should first read [RFC3016](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3016.txt), which describes the RTP format of MPEG-4 stream, then you'll know how to extract MPEG-4 frames from the RTP stream.